# File history error message

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I have been getting a message for some time to reconnect File History so I went to Control Panel and found File History.

When I opened it, it said that drive was disconnected. But the drive it listed did not exist on my computer so cannot to turn ON.

Have I done something ? How do I fix this ?

Windows 8.1 - The only drives showing are *C Drive* and D*VD (Drive D)*.  There is no (*Drive F*).

Comment: Show us a screenshot of the error that will be more helpful

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure the drive were never connected your computer your computer has probably used a network drive for backup. If you have no knowledge this backup routine or don't care about it, you can delete this file history. File history is just another word for backup.